# JavaScript coding interview first repeating character in array not working for null

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, count, repeat

### THE ISSUE

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm doing a [coding challenge on CodeFights](https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/pMvymcahZ8dY4g75q) using vanilla JavaScript to find and return the first repeating element in an array. My code works for 2 test arrays (`a` and `c`) but *not for the case where there are no repeating elements*.

### MY CODE

```js
console.clear();

var a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2];
var b = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1];
var c = ["apple", "orange", "grape", "orange", "grape"];

// create an object to store the counts
var counts = {};

function firstDuplicate(arr) {
    
    // loop through passed array of numbers
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        
        var num = arr[i];
        
        if (counts[num] === undefined) {
            counts[num] = 1;
        } else if (counts[num] == 1) {
            ++counts[num];
            return num;
        }
                
    }
    
    return -1;
    
}

console.log(firstDuplicate(a)); // 3
console.log(firstDuplicate(b)); // -1
console.log(firstDuplicate(c)); // orange
```

### MY QUESTION

I know my code is mostly right, so what I'm I missing/or have I misplaced something? How can I get the "null" case to work (when there are no repeating characters).

Comment: What happens if you move your `var counts = {}` declaration inside of your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to reset `counts` each time `firstDuplicate` is called. Otherwise each call will share the same object.

You are also referencing `a` in the `for` loop but should be referencing the `arr` function parameter.

```js
var a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2];
var b = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1];
var c = ["apple", "orange", "grape", "orange", "grape"];

function firstDuplicate(arr) {

    // move this definition inside the function so that each
    // time you call firstDuplicate() you get a new counts object.
    var counts = {};

    // use arr.length so that you are iterating through the arr parameter
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        var num = arr[i];

        if (counts[num] === undefined) {
            counts[num] = 1;
        } else if (counts[num] == 1) {
            ++counts[num];
            return num;
        }

    }

    return -1;

}

console.log(firstDuplicate(a)); // 3
console.log(firstDuplicate(b)); // -1
console.log(firstDuplicate(c)); // orange
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Works. ... I knew it was something simple like that, but my eyes just weren't catching it. Marked correct.